# Unable to parse JSON using Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, solr

I'm trying to do autosuggestion using solr along with jquery. For this I wrote the code below:

$(function() {

```
    $( "#artist" ).autocomplete({
        source: function( request, response ) {
            $.ajax({
                url: 'http://localhost:8983/solr/terms?terms.fl=heading&terms.prefix='
                +request.term+'&wt=json&json.nl=map',

                dataType: "jsonp",

                data: {
                    q: request.term,
                    rows: 10, 
                    omitHeader: true,
                },
                success: function( data ) {
                    response( $.map( data.terms.heading, function( item ) {
                        return {
                            label: item,
                            value: item
                        }
                    }
                    )
                    );
                }
            });
        },

        minLength: 2,
        select: function( event, ui ) {
            log( ui.item ?
                "Selected: " + ui.item.label :
                "Nothing selected, input was " + this.value);
        },
        open: function() {
            $( this ).removeClass( "ui-corner-all" ).addClass( "ui-corner-top" );
        },
        close: function() {
            $( this ).removeClass( "ui-corner-top" ).addClass( "ui-corner-all" );
        }

    });
});
```

I am getting the following error while running in Chrome

Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token :
The Json data I am getting is this

{"terms":{"heading":{"answer":24,"ansari":5}}}

I consulted the following link http://jqueryui.com/demos/autocomplete/#remote-jsonp but i am unable to find a solution. Please suggest what I am doing wrong

Comment: The code you've posted has an erroneous "});" at the end. Also should dataType: not be "json" and not "jsonp";

Comment: possibly try $.map( data.d.terms.heading, function( item )

Comment: could you post the jquery string ?

Answer (score 3):

You've (correctly?) specified JSONP to access a Cross Origin resource, but you haven't told Solr that you want it to emit JSONP instead of pure JSON.

Add `jsonp: 'json.wrf'` to the parameters to `$.ajax`.

More at http://xplus3.net/2010/09/21/solr-and-jsonp/

Comment: Its jsonp: 'json.wrf' and not json: 'json.wrf". Attached link is correct but the quoted answer is wrong